# Is my p-trap too low?

Tags: kitchens, sink

We recently installed a new sink and because the drain is in a different spot decided to replace the plumbing. This is the preliminary set up. My question; is the distance from the bottom of my p-trap to the exit pipe to great?

Don't mind the towels and baking dish we were just making sure we had no leaks.[image]

Comment: Have you known water to like flowing uphill?  Because this is almost making water flow uphill.

Comment: Dan, welcome to DIYSE. Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how we operate. "Thank you" comments are discouraged as flotsam. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 9):

You seem to have way more piping that you actually need. Some points to be made reference this picture:

[image]

1. There is freedom to rotate the whole disposer to optimize the piping.
2. You should be able to cut off a portion of the disposer tail piece at (A).
3. You should be able to eliminate part (B) and the elbow (E) to the left of it.
4. The sliding connection part of the p-trap at (C) can be directly attached at the cut off end of (A).
5. The other side of the p-trap (F) should be able to directly connect to the elbow piece at G enters the pipe at W on the back wall. Rotate the disposer and the amount that the elbow piece at the wall penetrates into the wall (W) to adjust the fit of the pieces going together. The amount you cut off of part A will be determined by what it takes to line up the opposite side of the p-trap (F) with the piece from the wall (G).
6. Note that the plumbing piece that you currently have at (G/W) will most likely need to be changed because the coupling at (F) is not normally a slip type joint. A p-trap can be purchased that has the mating part for the joint at (F) as a part of a kit.

Comment: Making it the way Michael has explained reduces the chance of a leak, removing the 90"s improves the flow great answer+

Answer (score 2):

I agree you have more piping than you need, but as long as the pipe W shown in the figure is lower than the garbage disposal outlet you are OK, otherwise water will sit in the garbage disposal.  Ideally, you want the highest part of the drain to be a few inches below the garbage disposal drain.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to contribute here.